# Excluding silk-to-silk rules for connected text and lines

Tags: pcb, altium, silkscreen

This question is quite specific so I thought that I'd give it a shot.

On my top overlay layer I have text and lines which looks similar to the video
[Phil's Lab #84](https://youtu.be/D2UaRPkRExw?si=v6VJmhjXehaScyY2) which can be seen at the timestamp 14:00.

[image: Screenshot of Phil's Lab #84 at timestamp 14:00]

Drawing this without any rule changes will generate a silk-to-silk violation which I find very annoying.

1. Is there any way to group/merge multiple "objects" together in Altium which will define them as one regarding rules?
2. If there is not, should I create the label and create preset lines as components, and just remove the lines which are not needed?
3. Am I overthinking and should I just create a rule for all labels, and if so how could I build a query to exclude lines attached to text effectively?

Currently I am using a rule to avoid any violation on my labels, but I can't help to think that there must be a simpler way to do this?

Altium Version: 23.9.2

Comment: Please edit your question to show a screen shot of the video you talk about. Reason: should the video or link get changed or deleted, your question will remain valid.

Comment: Silk-to-silk clearance rule, if you examine it closely, is actually Silk _text_ to any silk object clearance. You can have touching or overlapping lines, arcs, etc. but a text primitive is what triggers that violation. You could potentially convert text ([outside of Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/51234/2028)) to objects and treat it as a polygon/region.

Comment: Need the altium version number

Comment: Do you know you need the rule at all? Most fabs have automatic smoothing/merging, elimination of insignificant features, trimming around soldermask openings, etc.